# interactive pattern expression (with checkboxes)

Tags: javascript, html

I want to record and then express a pattern of interactions - the user triggering a combination of functions that play sounds. I believe that checkboxes are suited to this kind of functionality, but I can't find a good resource to learn about this type of interaction so was hoping for some guidance. An example of the type of functionality I am trying to achieve is [mlr for monome](http://monome.org/docs/app%3amlr) where a pattern of buttons presses is recorded then looped back.